# c# TaskDefinition uncheck Do not store password

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to create a task for Windows in C#.
Unfortunately I can't find how to uncheck the "Do not store password. The task will only have access to local resources"

[image: task definition, highlighting the option to not store password]

to do this I use a `TaskDefinition`:

```
TaskDefinition td = TaskService.Instance.NewTask();
DailyTrigger dt = new DailyTrigger();
dt.StartBoundary = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, task.Hour, task.Minute, 0);
dt.DaysInterval = 1;
dt.Enabled = true;
td.RegistrationInfo.Author = "Me";
td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "MyTask";
td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(task.ActionPath));
td.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.ServiceAccount;
                    TaskService.Instance.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(String.Format("MyTask", td, TaskCreation.Create, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"],PassWord.Text);
```

In LogonType I tried :

- InteractiveTokenOrPassword
- Password
- S4U
- ServiceAccount

I didn't see an option to uncheck this box directly either.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38075424/how-to-set-do-not-stored-password-the-task-will-only-have-access-to-local-compu

Comment: The positioning of the checkbox suggests the option is only relevant/applicable to certain logon types; do you intend to run the task as a domain user or as a service account?